# boost graph library adjacency_list: maintain EdgeList sorted by EdgeProperties

Tags: c++11, boost, graph, selector, adjacency-list

I'm trying to use a std::multiset container with strict weak ordering on the EdgeProperties for the EdgeList template parameter of boost::adacency_list

```
namespace boost {

struct propOrderedMultisetS { };
template <class ValueType>
struct container_gen<propOrderedMultisetS,ValueType> {
    struct less {
        bool operator() (const ValueType& lhs, const ValueType& rhs) const {
            return (lhs.get_property() < rhs.get_property());
        };
    };
    typedef std::multiset<ValueType, less> type;
};

struct MyVertexProp { int v; };
struct MyEdgeProp {
    bool operator<(const MyEdgeProp& rhs) const {
        return this->weight < rhs.weight;
    }
    double weight;
}

typedef adjacency_list<listS, listS, undirectedS, MyVertexProp, MyEdgeProp,
 no_property, propOrderedMultisetS> PropOrderedGraph;
}

using namespace boost;
int main() {
    PropOrderedGraph g;

    // ... adding some vertices and edges

    for (auto e_range=edges(g); e_range.first != e_range.second; ++e_range.first) {
        // works! prints the edges ordered by weight
        std::cout << g[*e_range.first].weight << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto v_range=vertices(g); v_range.first != v_range.second; ++v_range.first) {
        // works! prints all vertices (random order)
        std::cout << g[*v_range.first].v << std::endl;
    }

    auto first_vertex = *vertices(g).first;
    for (auto adj_v_range=adjacent_vertices(first_vertex, g); adj_v_range.first != adj_v_range.second; ++adj_v_range.first) {
        // problem: dereferencing causes compiler error, see below
        std::cout << g[*adj_v_range.first].v << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Dereferencing the iterator in the third for-loop causes a compiler error:

> /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:293:69: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘MyEdgeProp&’ from expression of type ‘const MyEdgeProp’
>          inline Property& get_property() { return m_iter->get_property(); }

Any ideas how I could fix that error or how else I could accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the graph library and now am using LEMON, which provides a class IterableValueMap for my task.